# PHPMailer 2 files same filesize are not sending both

Tags: php, phpmailer

It just so happens we have two files that are the exact same size that we some times try to send together. We can send anything else we want with these files but as soon as we include both of them it only sends the first one. I'll include my phpmailer code just to be safe but its worked thus far.

```
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    $mail->IsSendMail();
    $mail->SetFrom($from_addy, $from_name);
    foreach(explode(',',$to) as $address1){
        foreach(explode(';',$address1) as $address2){
            if($address2 != ''){
                $mail->AddAddress($address2);
            }
        }
    }

    $mail->WordWrap = 70;
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $css.$message;
    $mail->AltBody = nl2br($message);
    $mail->MsgHTML($css.$message);
    if(is_array($attachments)){
        foreach($attachments as $attachment){
            $file = file_get_contents($attachment['tmp_name']);
            $mail->AddStringAttachment($file,$attachment['name']);
            // I have put checks here and both attachments do make it this far.
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not checking the return value from `addStringAttachment` so you don't know if it's working or not. PHPMailer doesn't throw exceptions for everything, and while you've requested them, you're not catching them anyway. Why read the file and use `addStringAttachment` - why not read the attachment directly from the file with `addAttachment`? String attachments are more useful when you need to attach the results of a remote API call, PDF generation etc. Like this:

```
if (!$mail->addAttachment($attachment['tmp_name'], $attachment['name'])) {
    echo "Failed to attach ".$attachment['tmp_name'];
}
```

Why are you using `isSendmail()`? It's unlikely you need that.

You've not presented any evidence that it's got anything to do with the file size - it's not as if attachments are indexed by their size value or anything.

You're setting `AltBody` before calling `msgHTML()`, which overwrites `AltBody`. Calling `nl2br()` on `AltBody` contents is pointless because `AltBody` will usually be presented as plain text, so `<br>` tags will show up.

It looks like your `$attachment` array may be sourced from `$_FILES`, in which case it looks you are handling file uploads unsafely. read the PHP docs on that, and look at the "send file upload" example provided with PHPMailer.

Overall, it looks like you've based your code on a very old PHPMailer example, so make sure you're using the latest version, and look at the examples provided with it.

Comment: I can send 10 files and all send fine as long as they are different file sizes. If I had an 11th one that is the same file size as one of the original 10 it ignores it even though it makes it to the $mail->addStringAttachment. If I remove the one that is the same file size from the original 10  it will send the 11th one correctly. I've tried this with other file sets simply copying and renaming and I get the same issue of sending. That is my evidence.

Comment: So set a breakpoint, produce some debug output showing how it's happening. Assertion isn't enough - *we* need to be able to reproduce it.